# How to build Signalapp Server v9+

Tags: java, maven, signals, dropwizard

I am trying to build and self host [Signal Server](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server)

While trying building the latest version (v9.89.0) from the GitHub repository ([Signal Server](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server)) i faced `no main manifest attribute` issue.

**Steps i follow to run the project**

```
git clone https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server.git
cd Signal-Server 
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pexclude-abusive-message-filter 
java -jar service/target/TextSecureServer-*.jar server service/config/sample.yml
```

**Error: no main manifest attribute, in service/target/TextSecureServer-9.89.0.jar**

I am unable to find any guide corresponding to this version.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "no main manifest attribute" usually indicates that the JAR file you are trying to execute does not have the necessary manifest information to identify the main class.

In the case of Signal Server, starting from version 9.88.0, the project structure has changed, and the main JAR file name has been updated. Instead of using TextSecureServer-*.jar, you should use Signal-Server-*.jar as the main JAR file.

I recommend to try these codes:
Clone the Signal Server repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server.git
cd Signal-Server
```

Build the project using Maven:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pexclude-abusive-message-filter
```

Once the build is successful, navigate to the service directory:

```
cd service
```

Run the Signal Server using the correct main JAR file:

```
java -jar target/Signal-Server-9.89.0.jar server config/sample.yml
```

Comment: Hi i tried the steps you mentioned but i am unable to locate Signal-Server-0.89.0,jar file. 
Refer the attached screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cseM.png